# What is an effective way to get all gold crowns?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

I'm trying to get every achievement before the release of Iceborne on PC. And, I'm sure you guessed it, the only ones left on my list are "Miniature Crown Master" and "Giant Crown Master".

I've gotten a fair chunk of gold crowns so far (both small and big) and doing the event quests (Coral Waltz, Deep Green Blues...) aren't really worth it anymore.

I've heard that you need investigations with at least one silver and one gold reward to have a chance to spawn a gold crown monster. Is it true? Are there any more investigation parameters I should be on the look out for?

Basically, is there any way I can manually filter my investigations to find ones that have a (higher) chance of gold crowns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> doing the event quests (Coral Waltz, Deep Green Blues...) aren't really worth it anymore.

Those event quests offer the highest chances of gold crowns outside of quests with fixed sizes. Keep doing those quests.

For monsters not available in those quests, investigations *in general* will offer a chance of finding a giant or minature size monster, where optional quests usually don't. In the majority of assigned and optional quests, it is impossible to find a giant or minature size monster.

Investigations with at least one silver and gold reward do seem to increase the odds of crown monsters, but specifics are hard to find given the many variables and the limited number of times investigations can be posted.

Comment: I did these achievements recently and found also that investigations with 3 purples increased the chances.  Also, it seems that 1 gold and 1 silver is very literal (ie 2 gold and a 2 bronze won't work).  Finally, it may be worth mentioning save scumming a save file when you have one of the good investigations (I had to resort to this for my last one sadly).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a wide consensus on what you heard about the investigations. Though it seems to increase the chance to have a gold crown monster if the investigation has at least one gold and one silver reward, it is not necessarily limited to it. As I don't remember all my gold crowns, I will neither say its true or false that gold crowns can spawn outside of those investigations.

Additionally, there are some event quests that will ensure a gold crown in both directions (Great Jagras quest comes to mind). Sadly, those quests do not exist for all monsters. Also I think that the sizes for monsters in event quests is fixed. This means that the same quest will always have the exact same sizes (maybe mild variations; don't have proof).

Lastly, you can watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UkIDIO80mu0) video or have a look at all [these](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=mhw+gold+crown) videos for more efficient gold crown farming.

And to address you final question. There is no way to filter investigations in the way you want. It's just trial and error with the investigations we know that have a higher likelyhood of gold crown monsters

Answer (score -2):

Another useful Tip if you are trying to get good crowns on monsters is to use tools that show Things like Monster HP and Size.

I am using the tool **["Smart Hunter"](https://www.nexusmods.com/monsterhunterworld/mods/793)** and it shows me the monsters Hit-points and the Hp of it's body parts as well as other useful things like player damage on an monster.

Smart Hunter does also show the size of an monster indicated with the according crown symbol under it's name, which could be small silver/gold crown or large silver/gold crown.

As far as I know those helping Tools are not forbidden to use, since they do not alter your account and I did never hear any negative feedback about Smart Hunter so far.

---

What I do when I am looking for a specific crown is: I enter a quest, regardless if it's an investigation or one of those event quests and look if the monster in it has any gold crown size. 
This saves me a lot of time, since I can easily sort out quest with monsters that don't have the right size. (since doing the same investigation twice gives you a monster with the same size)

Comment: "doing the same exploration twice gives you a monster with the same size" is incorrect.

Comment: That would also only work on PC. No way to have it on PS4

Comment: I am talking about investigation. Had to leave work and could not find the correct english word there sorry. 
When I play investigations they are always the same monster sizes.
And the original Question was about MH:W for Pc, so I don't think this is answer is wrong, even if it does not work for all players.